# Затемнить фон в приложении по нажатию на imageview (Пример: alertdialog)

Tags: java, android

имеется такой код:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bacground"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".fragment3">
    <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Обработчик

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.b1:

    startActivity(getActivity(), a1.class);
    //тут я вызываю новое активти и фон android:background="@drawable/bacground" должен затемняться
    break;

    ...
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Задавайте цвет фона с альфаканалом.
Альфаканал - первые две буквы, он регулирует прозрачность.
Пример:

```
background="#DD000000"
```

Comment: так елси у меня уже задан background картинкой,но мнее ее нужно затемнить по нажатию на элемент ,тут как быть